# External Library and Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

Does External Android Library have their Android Manifest merged with the main app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it depends on the API you are using. Suppose you are using external API that doesn't require any hardware or network permission from OS than you don't need to add anything new in the `manifest` file. And if you are using external API that requires such permissions, then you must have to add them in your `manifest` file.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you specify `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in your project.properties file if you are using eclipse.

With android studio i think it's the default behaviour